# Remapping keys with xkb in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xkb, remapping, keys

My new laptop does not have right Control key. Instead it comes with useless more-less key. I tried to remap the key using xkb. In /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc there is a following line

```
key <LSGT> {    [ less, greater, bar, brokenbar ] };
```

I edited the line into

```
key <LSGT> {    [ Control_R, Control_R ] };
```

After restarting the laptop the key works either as right Ctrl or as "/"
xev -event keyboard gives the following output

```
KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
root 0x190, subw 0x0, time 137650, (152,49), root:(231,847),
state 0x0, keycode 94 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
root 0x190, subw 0x0, time 137821, (152,49), root:(231,847),
state 0x4, keycode 94 (keysym 0x2f, slash), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 61
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1f) ""
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Where does slash coming from??? I don't understand.

Comment: See [this document](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/node5.html#SECTION00053400000000000000) for xkb and control keys. Basically, you don't change the keysyms produced by the key but add the key to the control modifier map.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... and how can I change the keysyms? How do I make the key to be Control_R and nothing else? I can't find a good examples or clear explanations. Thank you.